# How to remove XML tags within a field of attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, attribute-table, excel, xml

I have this dataset I got it from Wikimapia ,containing bunch of fields . One of fields named "PopupInfo" contains xml tags :

[image]

and looks like this when in editing mode :

[image]

I want to remove these tags and keep the text between them . is there tool or script can do this .

Comment: Don't forget to mark a response as answered if it provides a solution for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Field Calculator](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/tables/fundamentals-of-field-calculations.htm) to do a regex substitution on the PopupInfo field, like this:

[image: Field Calculator Dialog]

The pre-logic function is:

```
import re

def RemoveTags(MyString):
    return re.sub('<.*?>', '',  MyString)
```